# Get git branch from several folders/repos

Tags: shell-script, git, for

I have a folder with several repositories inside. Is there any way I can run `git branch` or whatever *git* command inside each folder?

```
$ ls
project1            project2                project3            project4
```

And I'd like to have some kind of output like the following

```
$ command
project1 [master]
project2 [dev]
project3 [master]
project4 [master]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. `$1` should be the parent dir containing all of your repositories (or use "." for the current dir):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function git_branches()
{
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
        echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME <dir>" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    if [[ ! -d "$1" ]]; then
        echo "Invalid dir specified: '${1}'"
        return 1
    fi

    # Subshell so we don't end up in a different dir than where we started.
    (
        cd "$1"
        for sub in *; do
            [[ -d "${sub}/.git" ]] || continue
            echo "$sub [$(cd "$sub"; git  branch | grep '^\*' | cut -d' ' -f2)]"
        done
    )
}
```

You can make this its own script (but replace `$FUNCNAME` with `$0`), or keep it inside a function and use it in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in */
  do (cd $dir && echo "$dir [$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)]")
done
```

or even as an alias

```
alias brall='for dir in $(ls -d */);do (cd $dir && echo "$dir [$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)]") ; done'
```

It will output (almost) what you want.

```
project1/ [master]
project2/ [dev]
project3/ [master]
project4/ [master]
```

Comment: `$(ls -d */)` is a brittle way of saying `*/`.

Comment: I don't get it, how would you do that : 'for dir in */ ... ' ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that: `for d in */`

Comment: Ok, I'm far from an expert in bash and it certainly works in other version of shell. But with my version of zsh (5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0)), it doesn't work : "zsh: no matches found: */"

Comment: Then there are no matches. In that case, your loop would have failed as well.

Comment: Right, pebkac problem

Answer (score 1):

I had to do some tweaks as the git directories were in some sub- sub-folders. It also supports from the cwd or dir specified on $1. Here is an alias to add to .bashrc:

```
git_branches() {
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
        search_dir=$(pwd)
        echo "Using current dir: '${search_dir}'"
    else
        search_dir=$1
    fi
    
    if [[ ! -d "$search_dir" ]]; then
        echo "Invalid dir specified: '${search_dir}'"
        return 1
    fi
    
    # Subshell so we don't end up in a different dir than where we started.
    (
        cd "$search_dir"
        for dir in $(find . -name .git -type d -prune); do
        (
            cd $dir
            echo "$dir [$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)]"
        );
        done
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} branch
```

You can use any git command in place of branch. for e.g:

```
ls | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} pull --rebase
ls | xargs -P10 -I{} git -C {} fetch
```

Only caveat is output may not contain the directory name. But if it is not an issue, this command is simple.

Answer (score 0):

The basic command is

```
git branch --show-current
```

in the appropriate folder

so, one liner can be:

```
for d in project*; do cd "$d" && b="`git branch --show-current`" && cd - >/dev/null && echo "$d [$b]"; done
```

This can be made an alias or put into a script to be used as a command

Comment: Use `$(command)` instead of backticks.

Comment: No problem. I prefer backtick. $(command) will also work. Readability is the same for me.